# How would I setup a data stream between an Oculus Go app, built on Unity, and an app on a "host device" connected via USB?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb, rtmp, oculusgo

I want to setup a data stream between an Oculus Go app, built on Unity, and an app on a "host device" (macOS) connected via USB. The intention here is to stream multiple video streams to the Oculus Go app, along with streaming other data between the two devices in both directions.

There's obviously a few different parts to this:

- macOS app
- Video stream of content
- USB connection, so non-remote streaming
- Multiple data streams
- Oculus Go (running a version of Android)
- Unity app

I'm wondering how I should go about making this connection happen.

I've began with [CocoaSplit](https://www.cocoasplit.com/), a Mac app which allows streaming from various sources, to an output. That output can be an RTMP/Network, so [setting up an RTMP server on my Mac](https://github.com/sallar/mac-local-rtmp-server) and then setting that as the destination, allows me to stream to there. This is still all happening on my Mac though, no interaction with the Oculus Go yet.

I have my Oculus Go connected via USB, with [ADB debugging enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#Enabling).

I'm not sure what my next steps are from here.

- With Unity, can I do enough sophisticated networking to send and receive data over a data stream, and receive multiple video streams?
- How do I go about setting up these streams over USB?